# About the camera view

Tags: camera

I want to shoot around a target object in a large sphere by moving the camera 360 degrees, but in normal view, the object's background shows the sphere because it is naturally shot in the sphere, but in camera view, there is a hole in the cube. I don't know why this happens. Does anyone know?[image]

Comment: Maybe because of the camera's clipping settings? In the camera's properties under _Lens_ > _Clip Start_ / _End_?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's resolved.